# i have an error when you install express-handlebars

Tags: express

erorr :

TypeError: exphbs is not a function

code :

var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout : 'main'}));

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

```
res.render('home');
```

});

app.listen(3000);

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in express-handelbars and I encountered the same issue.
If you try `console.log(exphbs)` after your `exphbs` variable been defined, you'll see something like this:

```
{
  ExpressHandlebars: [Function: ExpressHandlebars],
  create: [Function: create],
  engine: [Function: engine]
}
```

Consider above, I found a working solution to setup:

```
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');    
const hbs = handlebars.create({
      extname: "hbs",
      defaultLayout: "main",
      layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts',
      partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials'
    });
    app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine);
    app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Hope it is helpful.